# How to send continuous dynamic data using Boost Asio?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to send continuous data using Boost Asio from my PC to a TCP client. The data is a string that contains coordinates of an object being tracked using my webcam. Therefore, the frequency of this data is very high for every frame being captured. Since there are two threads, the camera capture and message sending, async method has to be used, I'm guessing. According to what I have read, I should do the write in start() by using async_write() and then update the message in handle_write(), but I'm unable to figure out how to do it such that I don't lose data from any frame - where should I place my capture coordinates code and how should I update the message being sent.

Answer (score 2):

Having a pool of two threads:
Thread 1 continuously read your webcam and push message in an [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)
Thread 2 which is asio-able pull one by one the buffer and TCP send that data
Of course you have to synchronize access to the circular buffer, there is an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/examples.html#circular_buffer.examples.bounded_buffer_example) how to do that. You have to take care of the size of the circular buffer.

I imagine another solution with two asio threads working with same ioservice, first thread:

1. read the webcam
2. call asio::post send routine with binded webcam data
3. call asio::dispatch the same "read webcam" routine

The second thread is the socket one, just TCP sending the webcam data.

In that scenario the circular buffer is replaced by the "asio object's event processing loop", you do not have to worry on synchronizing access.
But I'm wondering how to handle the case where the "event queue" is filled faster than emptying, hum ...

Comment: Actually, I want to use the data instantaneously, so if there is lag between capture and send and the queue keeps piling up, the delayed data will have no use for me. So, I think it'll be better if I somehow keep only the most recent one in the queue. Will this somehow simplify your solution, like, do away with the need to use buffer?

Comment: @Stat7 Use a buffer with only one element ! And UDP instead Tcp

Comment: Thanks Jean. How would UDP help?

Comment: Come on! You have to learn some basis if you want to doa killer app ! Anyway very shortly, UDP has less protocol overhead than TCP, so you can loose some data (but you accept that) but speed is higher